# Elementos absolute responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive

estoy haciendo un `carousel` y tengo las siguientes flechas en la imagen que son las que cambian de imágenes, pero estoy tratando de acomodarlas en su lugar y que a su vez se auto ajusten(responsive)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi `div` donde tengo las imagenes

```
<div className="arrows">
          <img
            onClick={() =>
              selected === 0
                ? setSelected(sLength - 1)
                : setSelected((prev) => prev - 1)
            }
            src={LeftArrow}
            alt=""
          />
          <img
            onClick={() =>
              selected === sLength - 1
                ? setSelected(0)
                : setSelected((prev) => prev + 1)
            }
            src={RightArrow}
            alt=""
          />
        </div>
```

Y el `CSS` con el que he estado probando es el siguiente

```
.arrows {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  transform: translate( -50%, -50% );
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 42%;
  left:54.5%;
  gap: 97%;
}
.arrows > :first-child{
  filter: brightness(0) saturate(100%) invert(100%) sepia(0%) saturate(7482%) hue-rotate(19deg) brightness(118%) contrast(93%); 
}

.arrows > img {
  width: 1.5vw;
  height: 1.5vw;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

He estado investigando y he visto que use `porcentajes`, que use tamaños como `vw` pero pues solo he logrado hacer el diseño `responsive` en pantallas móvil, para las otras pantallas las flechas se desajustan.

Comment: Tienes posibilidad de usar algún FW como Boostrap?

Answer (score 0):

Todas las imágenes en un documento HTML deben ser con un `width: 100%` y `height: 100%` junto con `object-fit: cover`; y lo que hay que modificar y ajustar es su contenedor padre.

```
img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover
}
```

En este caso el contenedor padre es `arrow`.

1. El `display: flex` por defecto tiene la dirección horizontal y no necesita `flex-direction: row`.
2. Debe tener un ancho fijo (por lo menos un `max-width`) y con la medida de `vw`; y un alto especifico (de por lo menos `max-height`) con la medida de `vh`

```
.arrows {
  display: flex;
  width: 1.5vw;
  height: 1.5vh;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transform: translate( -50%, -50% );
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 42%;
  left:54.5%;
  gap: 97%;
}
```

Recomiendo que no uses la medida `vw` y `vh` sino `rem` o `em` para estos casos. El resto sería trabajarlo bien adaptando a tu estilo y requerimiento.

Comment: Entiendo. Ya las arrows redimensionan cada vez que cambia la pantalla pero el problema que tengo ahora es que al realizar el gap de las arrows. Como te puedes fijar en la imagen de la pregunta tengo las arrows separadas, pero al ir revisando otras resoluciones no se ajustan bien